# Improving java web app deployment process inside a docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

Lets say I have a bunch of assembled `war`s each of those is about 80-100 MB. I have created images for all of them based on Tomcat:8-jre8 official image and basically each of those images only contain tomcat with his dependencies and my war file.

Normally when deploying one of those apps onto a server (`tomcat`) it takes about 20-80 seconds depending on the size of the deployed app and the number of things it has to initialize on startup.

When deploying such `war`s in docker containers the deployment process is couple of times longer, for example, an app that normally would deploy in 20 seconds needs about 60 seconds inside a docker container.

my `Dockerfile`s are kind of basic

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8
ENV spring.profiles.active=dev
ADD foo.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY bar.properties /root/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I have tried both running a separate tomcat server for each web app and deploying all of them to the single tomcat server but the problem still persists.
Are there any ways of improving the deployment time for web apps inside docker containers ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `docker-machine`? If so, it takes some time to send the files to the docker engine so there is little you can do about it. For development purposes you can make another `Dockerfile` that uses volumes to sync files between the host and the container so you won't need to rebuild every time you decide to deploy.

Comment: yes, I use docker-machine. I don't have to redeploy often, I use Jrebel with remote-server, it adds a couple of seconds to the deploy time but still offers way too much. Btw, I haven't heard that docker volumes are capable of swapping classes into deployed web-app.

Comment: It is not, you'll have to handle this yourself. There are probably community-built machines that can do this. Sorry, but I can't help you with much that Java-specific matter - I rarely use Java

Comment: as I said, redeployment is not a problem, even the deployment of Java web apps is not a problem here, the only problem is deploying big sized applications within docker container. As I mentioned before deployment of identical war to tomcat from cmd/from inside Eclipse takes half of deployment time inside container.

Comment: Try `docker diff yourcontainername` and see how much files will be created and added inside the container. This will be done at each recreation! Try volumes on those folders in order to increase reuse and write/read speed.

Comment: @maybeg, tried that out, the files that are needed by tomcat itself are cached by docker, and adding some additional files to the container doesn't seem to take long time (I mean all *.jar and *.class files). The most problematic part is establishing connection with external systems and eventually connection speed between the guest and the host machine.

Comment: Are we now talking about container startup time or container build time? Sounds like you rebuild the container each time and then start it up. I am not surprised that rebuilding and restarting takes longer then throwing a war in an already started tomcat. I am confused what we are comparing here, basically each scenario you do on your development comp you can do with Docker/Containers/Volumes. Also with JRebel and everything. If the problem is internally, e.g. connecting to a database, then take a profiler like JProfiler and hook into the bootstrap. Maybe you run into a timeout.

Comment: @maybeg, no, I've run the container once and then I just use `docker start container-name` when I want to use that container again.

Comment: One thing that is worth checking is VM settings (I assume you're using VirtualBox to run docker-machine). Open check System->Processor and System->Acceleration settings - you might be utilizing only 1 CPU core.

Comment: @AlexanderLazarov, I've tried to play with Oracle VM Box options according to stuff over here [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html), changed networking settings, gave more RAM and gave 2 CPU cores, the only thing that changed is that I can now run 6 tomcat instances instead of 4, but the startup time is kind of the same.